# mongodb remote connection problems

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, iptables

I took several days trying to configure my environment running linux mongodb without results. This platform is running on AWS EC2.

mongodb is configured with `auth=true`commented, and with `port=27017`

My problem is when I try to connect remotely (or even from the same machine), I got:

```
-bash-4.1# mongo myIP:27017/mybd 
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: myIP:27017/mybd
Wed Apr  2 20:57:28.250 Error: couldn't connect to server myIP:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
exception: connect failed
```

But if I try with localhost:

```
-bash-4.1# mongo localhost:27017/mybd 
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: localhost:27017/mybd
>
```

Now more info:

```
-bash-4.1# netstat -a
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 *:27017                     *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:28017                     *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp              *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0     48 ip-10-187-41-156.ec2.in:ssh 186-79-194-159.baf.mo:55311 ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN


-bash-4.1# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:27017 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:27017 state ESTABLISHED
```

And finally, I've made sure that the security group is right. I've opened 27017 and 28017 to anything from the outside with 0.0.0.0/0.

Answer (score 3):

edit your /etc/mongod.conf

bind_ip = 0.0.0.0

that's it,now you can connect to your remote mongodb instance.